# XQuery: how does the function "doc" work

Tags: xml, xquery

I am using [XQuery tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery) to learn the XML and XQuery.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_example.asp) is an simple example that I am testing.

If I copy the whole xml file above to the XQuery tester and try this xquery `/bookstore/book/title`, I can get what I want.

Now I try to use the function `doc()`
I don't know how it works. I know that this function needs a parameter as the xml file. So I think we need the whole path of the file. But in the example above, it just said that we could use this function like this: `doc("books.xml")`. I am confused: where is "books.xml"?

I also tried to create a xml file named "books.xml" in my PC and pass the parameter like this: `doc("C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\books.xml")` but I got an error: `Premature end of file`.

Could someone tell me how to use the function `doc()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `doc()` gets a URI as parameter. The URI is the name of an XML document. That XML document is returned as the value of calling the function. Your processor can define a mapping from URI names to the file system, or to documents stored in a database, or anything else.

In your case, it seems that you are using a processor through a webpage.  The probability that it lets you resolve `doc()` from your local file system is very low, as it is (almost) impossible for a webpage to access a host's file system.

It seems that the below panel let you **paste the content** of your document though (then is used to display the result of evaluating the query, which is a bit weird).

If you need more details about how `dcc()` behaves on XPath Tester, I am afraid you'll need to ask them directly.

Answer (score 0):

You must use URI name convention, which in your example would be doc("file:///C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/books.xml"). That´s in Windows of course.